# Redirect Nashorn stdout and stderror

Tags: java, nashorn

Trying to redirect the Nashorn scripting engine from within a Java class. This is how I'm initializing it right now.  I'd like to redirect any output from the scripts the engine runs.

```
String[] nashornArgs = new String[] {"-strict", "--no-java",
                "--no-syntax-extensions", "-dump-on-error"};
NashornScriptEngineFactory factory = new NashornScriptEngineFactory();
ScriptEngine engine = factory.getScriptEngine(nashornArgs);
```

I know Nashorn has the following args (below) but I'm not sure how to initialize correctly and in a manner where any output is discarded by the program.  Maybe create a temp file and then delete the temp file once the engine is done?  Seems messy to me.

---

--stderr (Redirect stderr to a filename or to another tty, e.g. stdout)

param: output console

--stdout (Redirect stdout to a filename or to another tty, e.g. stderr)

param: output console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redirect output like this:

```
package com.example;

import java.io.StringWriter;

import javax.script.ScriptContext;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptException;

import jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngineFactory;

public class Nashorn {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ScriptException {
        String[] arguments = new String[] {"-strict", "--no-java", "--no-syntax-extensions", "-dump-on-error"};
        NashornScriptEngineFactory factory = new NashornScriptEngineFactory();
        ScriptEngine engine = factory.getScriptEngine(arguments);
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        ScriptContext context = engine.getContext();
        context.setWriter(sw);
        context.setErrorWriter(sw);
        engine.eval("print('hello world')");
        System.out.println("redirected output: " + sw);
    }
}
```

Comment: I attempted that however did not work.  Was able to still print from within a script.  Do I need to reset the engine's context?

Comment: @MarkII I have edited my answer providing complete code example which demonstrates stdout/stderr redirection for Nashorn.

Comment: Let me try your updated comment first then I'll see if I need to post anything

Comment: StringWriter worked!  Also like how it allows me to print it out later if I want.  Thanks @yanys